# Is there a command or a piece of code that prevents the Python(command line) from closing immediately after executing the code?

Tags: python, python-2.7

I need your help. I'm a newbie and I'm learning python. I know to write basic codes. But, when I execute the code in Python(command line) it closes immediately. Is there any piece of code that can prevent this from happening or a trick? Please help me out. Cheers!
P.S: I use Python 2.7 in Windows.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're seeing a Command Prompt open and immediately close when you double-click your `.py` file, that's to be expected - it's not how you're supposed to run a console-based Python script.

What you should do is start a Command Prompt via the Start menu, then run your program by typing `c:\python27\python.exe myscript.py` or similar.

Alternatively, use a Python IDE (eg. Idle) or an editor (eg. Scite) that can run Python scripts.

Answer (score 2):

The usual way to do this is from outside of Python, as RichieHindle's answer shows.

However, if you want to create a .py script that you can double-click, and it will wait for a response before exiting, you can just add this to the end of your program:

```
raw_input('Press ENTER to quit')
```

(If you've written .BAT files before, this is similar to writing `PAUSE` in a batch file.)

Answer (score 1):

python 2

```
raw_input('Press Enter To Continue')
```

python 3

```
input('Press Enter To Continue')
```